# Fitbit API unable to fetch data synced through Fitbit device i.e Blaze

Tags: php, api, fitbit

I am trying to fetch data using the following link:- https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/activity/ and API :- `GET https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/[user-id]/activities/date/[date].json` and getting response array as below

```
Array(
[result] => Array
    (
        [activities] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [activityId] => 90013
                        [activityParentId] => 90013
                        [activityParentName] => Walk
                        [calories] => 25
                        [description] => Walking less than 2 mph, strolling very slowly
                        [distance] => 0.271426
                        [duration] => 355000
                        [hasStartTime] => 1
                        [isFavorite] => 
                        [lastModified] => 2016-11-29T19:11:42.000Z
                        [logId] => 5007419020
                        [name] => Walk
                        [startDate] => 2016-11-30
                        [startTime] => 00:34
                        [steps] => 342
                    )

            )

        [goals] => Array
            (
                [activeMinutes] => 30
                [caloriesOut] => 2157
                [distance] => 8.05
                [floors] => 10
                [steps] => 10000
            )

        [summary] => Array
            (
                [activeScore] => -1
                [activityCalories] => 55
                [caloriesBMR] => 1257
                [caloriesOut] => 1300
                [distances] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [activity] => Walk
                                [distance] => 0.271426
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [activity] => total
                                [distance] => 0.48
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [activity] => tracker
                                [distance] => 0.42
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [activity] => loggedActivities
                                [distance] => 0.271426
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [activity] => veryActive
                                [distance] => 0.09
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [activity] => moderatelyActive
                                [distance] => 0.11
                            )

                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [activity] => lightlyActive
                                [distance] => 0.16
                            )

                        [7] => Array
                            (
                                [activity] => sedentaryActive
                                [distance] => 0.12
                            )

                    )

                [elevation] => 0
                [fairlyActiveMinutes] => 5
                [floors] => 0
                [heartRateZones] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [caloriesOut] => 37.9099
                                [max] => 98
                                [min] => 30
                                [minutes] => 25
                                [name] => Out of Range
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [caloriesOut] => 33.193
                                [max] => 137
                                [min] => 98
                                [minutes] => 9
                                [name] => Fat Burn
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [caloriesOut] => 0
                                [max] => 166
                                [min] => 137
                                [minutes] => 0
                                [name] => Cardio
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [caloriesOut] => 0
                                [max] => 220
                                [min] => 166
                                [minutes] => 0
                                [name] => Peak
                            )

                    )

                [lightlyActiveMinutes] => 6
                [marginalCalories] => 33
                [sedentaryMinutes] => 1426
                [steps] => 789
                [veryActiveMinutes] => 3
            )

    )

[code] => 200
[content_type] => application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

)

but the problem is this array just provides me the data of the activity that has been done using Fitbit application. But I have to fetch complete data whether its by the Fitbit application or Fitbit device i.e blaze.

Answer (score 0):

Just glancing at the API, I believe you need to use `activities/tracker/`. The API states that this represents the daily activity values logged by the tracker device only, excluding manual activity log entries. So you just need to add `tracker` to your `GET`.

**Tracker Activities:**

```
activities/tracker/calories  
activities/tracker/steps  
activities/tracker/distance  
activities/tracker/floors  
activities/tracker/elevation  
activities/tracker/minutesSedentary  
activities/tracker/minutesLightlyActive  
activities/tracker/minutesFairlyActive  
activities/tracker/minutesVeryActive  
activities/tracker/activityCalories
```

Comment: Tracker is giving us different response, but we need as above response which is fetched at key--> [Activities]. We are still getting just app synced data..but not by device.

Comment: I don't think you have a tracker assigned with this ID. According to the API. if you specify activities by date using `GET https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/[user-id]/activities/date/[date].json`, it will show you all activities. Whether it be tracker (Device) or the application. To filter the result by device, you need to specify the key ['tracker']. If you look at the example response at https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/activity/, you will see within the activities --> Summary, it shows app input and device (tracker). It also shows an elevation value (Tracker/Device Value) greater than 0.

Comment: We need all activities, both by app or device. The problem is we are just getting app synced data not the device one's.

Comment: As mentioned previously, I don't think you have a device assigned with the ID you are using or your search date needs to be widened. Have you tried getting the lifetime stats using `GET https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/[user-id]/activities.json` to see if device information is showing.

Comment: Yes we tried this as well but still not getting complete data.